# Create combined numpy array without explicit loop/comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a long NumPy array that I need to organize in a "pattern" like so:

```py
import numpy as np

# long array:
a = np.array(
    [
        1.3,
        -1.8,
        0.3,
        11.4,
        # ...
    ]
)


def pattern(x: float):
    return np.array(
        [
            [x, 0, 0],
            [0, x, 0],
            [0, 0, x],
            [+x, +x, +x],
            [-x, -x, -x],
        ]
    )


out = np.array([pattern(x) for x in a])
print(out.shape)
```

```
(4, 5, 3)
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to construct `out` *without* the explicit loop over `a`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `map(pattern, x)`?

Comment: Are you wondering if there's something built into numpy that will do this loop?

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. Ideally without moving around the array in memory.

Answer (score 7):

Replace the `pattern` function by an array of -1/0/1 values and broadcast a multiplication:

```
pattern = np.array([[ 1,  0,  0],
                    [ 0,  1,  0],
                    [ 0,  0,  1],
                    [+1, +1, +1],
                    [-1, -1, -1]])

out = a[:,None,None] * pattern[None]
```

Variant with [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
out = np.einsum('i,jk->ijk', a, pattern)
```

Another approach with [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) (less efficient):

```
m1 = np.array([[ True, False, False],
               [False,  True, False],
               [False, False,  True],
               [ True,  True,  True],
               [False, False, False]])
m2 = np.array([[False, False, False],
               [False, False, False],
               [False, False, False],
               [False, False, False],
               [ True,  True,  True]])

x = a[:,None,None]
out = np.select([m1, m2], [x, -x], 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[[  1.3,   0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   1.3,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0. ,   1.3],
        [  1.3,   1.3,   1.3],
        [ -1.3,  -1.3,  -1.3]],

       [[ -1.8,  -0. ,  -0. ],
        [ -0. ,  -1.8,  -0. ],
        [ -0. ,  -0. ,  -1.8],
        [ -1.8,  -1.8,  -1.8],
        [  1.8,   1.8,   1.8]],

       [[  0.3,   0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0.3,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0. ,   0.3],
        [  0.3,   0.3,   0.3],
        [ -0.3,  -0.3,  -0.3]],

       [[ 11.4,   0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,  11.4,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0. ,  11.4],
        [ 11.4,  11.4,  11.4],
        [-11.4, -11.4, -11.4]]])
```

Timings:

```
# list comprehension
14.8 µs ± 1.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# broadcasting
1.87 µs ± 85.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

# einsum
3.07 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

# select
42.2 µs ± 2.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What I don't like about this is that is uses an arithmetic operation for something that's only data organization. This shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer IMO that's the most efficient. And after all, your function also does the same (+/- x) ;)

Comment: What makes you think it's the most efficient? Don't you think the artificial arithmetic operation makes this slower than necessary?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Because multiplication is fast, I'll add another approach but it's less efficient.

Comment: Note that a multiplication-based approach will produce undesirable results with nans and infinities, since nan * 0 and inf * 0 are both nan instead of 0.

Comment: @user2357112 that's why I had provided the `select` approach, you can use it with arbitrary operations like in the original function. That said, given OP's example multiplication seems a reasonably short, explicit, and efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed-up the generation using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) (well, to certain amount, see the benchmark):

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def generate_numba(a):
    pattern = np.array(
        [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [+1, +1, +1], [-1, -1, -1]], dtype=np.float64
    )

    out = np.empty(shape=(len(a), 5, 3), dtype=np.float64)
    for i, aa in enumerate(a):
        out[i] = pattern * aa

    return out
```

---

Benchmark using `perfplot`:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot
from numba import njit


@njit
def generate_numba(a):
    pattern = np.array(
        [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [+1, +1, +1], [-1, -1, -1]], dtype=np.float64
    )

    out = np.empty(shape=(len(a), 5, 3), dtype=np.float64)
    for i, aa in enumerate(a):
        out[i] = pattern * aa

    return out


pattern = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [+1, +1, +1], [-1, -1, -1]])


def generate_einsum(a):
    out = np.einsum("i,jk->ijk", a, pattern)
    return out


def generate_kron(a):
    out = np.kron(a.reshape(-1, 1), pattern).reshape(-1, *np.shape(pattern))
    return out


a = np.array(
    [
        1.3,
        -1.8,
        0.3,
        11.4,
    ]
)
assert np.allclose(generate_numba(a), generate_einsum(a))
assert np.allclose(generate_numba(a), generate_kron(a))

np.random.seed(0)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: -50 + np.random.sample(n) * 100,
    kernels=[generate_numba, generate_einsum, generate_kron],
    labels=["numba", "einsum", "kron"],
    n_range=[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```

Generates this graph on my machine AMD 5700x:

[image]

So to ~100-150 values in `a` numba version is more performant. For large `a` seems the `np.kron` version is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `np.kron` + `np.reshape`, e.g.,

```
pat = np.array(
        [
            [1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 1],
            [-1, -1, -1],
        ])

np.kron(a.reshape(-1, 1), pat).reshape(-1, *np.shape(pat))
```

and you will obtain

```
array([[[  1.3,   0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   1.3,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0. ,   1.3],
        [  1.3,   1.3,   1.3],
        [ -1.3,  -1.3,  -1.3]],

       [[ -1.8,  -0. ,  -0. ],
        [ -0. ,  -1.8,  -0. ],
        [ -0. ,  -0. ,  -1.8],
        [ -1.8,  -1.8,  -1.8],
        [  1.8,   1.8,   1.8]],

       [[  0.3,   0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0.3,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0. ,   0.3],
        [  0.3,   0.3,   0.3],
        [ -0.3,  -0.3,  -0.3]],

       [[ 11.4,   0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,  11.4,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0. ,  11.4],
        [ 11.4,  11.4,  11.4],
        [-11.4, -11.4, -11.4]]])
```

Comment: I've updated my benchmark and added the `np.kron` version. Seems for very large `a` arrays this is the fastest.

Comment: @AndrejKesely aha, that's interesting, I didn't expect it would be that fast :P